# T-sql TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION - now I need to decrypt the output text file in c#

Tags: c#, t-sql

How do I decrypt triple des encryption the file  in c#. Which namespace?

This is the output file:

```
FirstCol  secondCol  EncryptSecondCol
1         value      00E35587C2CCEF4683B98686ED0483480100000054ABDFFB520111778B477223D1CD853F3CE33B4DD96C0F96
```

The sql that I used to create the encrypted file below:

```
--CREATE MASTER KEY
--ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'jjvc1234%';
--GO

---- Create a test certificate
--CREATE CERTIFICATE Tasc
--   WITH SUBJECT = 'Tasc Encryption', 
--   EXPIRY_DATE = '20301231';
--GO

--CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
--WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
--BY CERTIFICATE Tasc
--GO

Declare @TestTable table(FirstCol varchar(8),secondCol varchar(100),EncryptSecondCol VARBINARY(256))
insert into @TestTable 
values('1','value',null);

--select * from @TestTable 

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE Tasc
UPDATE @TestTable
SET EncryptSecondCol = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),secondCol)

select * from @TestTable 

--OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
--BY CERTIFICATE Tasc
--SELECT FirstCol,SecondCol,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DECRYPTBYKEY(EncryptSecondCol)) AS DecryptSecondCol
--FROM @TestTable




--CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey -- close them drop

--DROP SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
--GO
--DROP CERTIFICATE Tasc
--GO
--DROP MASTER KEY
--GO


-- BACKUP CERTIFICATE Tasc
--TO FILE = 'c:\Temp\TestCert.cer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# Provides Triple DES as part of the core cryptography libraries

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx

Comment: An example of how to decrypt a text file would be nice.

Comment: I will answer this question on monday. you will love it!

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do this - you now have your key in two places, which makes it that much harder to secure. If you give one system permission to encrypt using a symmetric key generally the same system should be doing the decryption.

In any case you can't export symmetric encryption keys from SQL, and as you used a certificate to act as a source for the symmetric key, and didn't provide an IDENTITY_VALUE or KEY_SOURCE when creating the symmetric cert SQL used random values for generating the key, so you can't reproduce it in C# either.

Comment: I need to do this my friend is not an option.

Comment: Except it isn't, you can't export the symmetric key used for encryption, or easily recreate it, so what you're suggesting is, for all intents and purposes, impossible (limits of my knowledge excluded obviously).

Comment: I was hoping I could use the certificate in the other computer.

Comment: The certificate only protects the symmetric key used to encrypt, it is *not* the key.